# Save canvas fragment in memory, JS

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

How can I save fragment in memory?

```
var img = document.getElementById('img1');
ctx.save();
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 180 * 45);
ctx.drawImage(img, 100, 100, img.width, img.height); 
ctx.restore();
```

And now I want save this fragment (already rotated) to some array, and then just call drawImage without new rotating.

Is it real in JS and canvas or I should rotate image every time, when I want draw it?

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = canvas.toDataURL();
```

may assist you with storing the canvas data in memory.  It can then be re-drawn from this url later. e.g.

```
img.src = url;
ctx.drawImage(img,0,0);
```

Comment: Can I save not all canvas, but only last drawed element?

Comment: Ah yes I see what you mean.  I'm afraid I don't know.  My (limited) knowledge of HTML5 and canvas would suggest that you cannot.  You could store instructions to re-create the fragment, but that may not be satisfactory..

Answer (score 0):

I assume what you want is to store a rotated image.

To do it, most easy way is to create a canvas, then draw rotated into this canvas : you now have your rotated image inside a canvas, that you might want to transform into an image.
However, the security policy prevents you from creating an image out of a canvas if you used an image coming from another domain. So be sure to use canvas only in such a case.

http://jsbin.com/gemijekewewu/1/edit?js,output

(thx @markE for careful reading).

```
function getRotatedImage(sourceImage, provideImage) {
   var cv    = document.createElement('canvas');
   cv.width  = sourceImage.height;
   cv.height = sourceImage.width;
   var ctx   = cv.getContext('2d');
   ctx.translate(cv.width/2, cv.height/2);
   ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
   ctx.drawImage(sourceImage, -cv.width/2, -cv.height/2);
  if (provideImage) {
      var img=new Image();
      img.src= cv.toDataURL();
      return img;
  } else
      return cv;
}
```

use with :

```
// during the init ...
var rotatedImage=getRotatedImage(myImage);

// ... later ...
ctx.drawImage(rotatedImage, ... , ...);
```

Comment: Hm ) And if I want to do it about 30 times per second - it kill my browser?)

Comment: Think a bit, and read better : you do the rotation once, store the result, and when app is running you use the rotated image.